# Android Things - Using both virtual keyboard and physical keyboard(barcode scanner) in Pi

Tags: android, android-things

I have a USB barcode scanner and I hope the virtual keyboard can still appear in EditText objects even if the barcode scanner has been connected. I can achieve this through the following code:

```
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), "show_ime_with_hard_keyboard", "1");
```

This program execution requires special system permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

The code runs well and the virtual keyboard can appear when testing. But I could not build my app in Android Things Console because of permission denied.

> Failed to load apps Permission denied.
>
> [app-debug.apk] has prohibited permissions:
>   android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
>   [Error in Android Things Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnZ8n.png)

Does anybody know how to build my app as system app of android things or the solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you giving the permission on runtime?

Comment: The permission of WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is config in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I found another solution. If the value of "show_ime_with_hard_keyboard" is "0",  I will show the ime dialog and ask user to enable it. (refer to this: https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Android-with-hardware-keyboard-force-show-hide-Soft-Keyboard-on-EditText)